# Errno 111 Connection refused error, between flask server and raspberry pi over ethernet

Tags: python, python-requests, raspberry-pi, ethernet

I am trying to send data through an http request with the python `requests` library froma  raspberry pi to my local computer connected by an ethernet cable. When trying to send data from the raspberry pi I get an `Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))` error. I have attached the full stack trace below.

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/PROJECT_NAME/src/client/send_data.py", line 7, in <module>
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload,)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='0.0.0.0', port=6000): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0xb5a6b1b0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

I was expecting the response to return a simple string as my route is a simple hello world function. The client file and flask server minimum examples are attached below.

`client.py`

```py
import requests
url = "https://0.0.0.0:6000/"

payload={}
headers = {}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload,)

print(response.text)
```

`app.py`

```py
import flask
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def hello():
    return flask.jsonify("Hello World!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=6000, debug=True)
```

I have tried disabling my firewall but this has not fixed the issue. I am also developing on the Pi through ssh using the vscode remote development extension and there is no issue with connection on that front. Any help is appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Your client needs to use the PC server's IP address, not 0.0.0.0. The address 0.0.0.0 is shorthand that means *"on all interfaces on the local machine"*, so when you start Flask on that address it will respond to requests from the local machine internally and from any other machine attached via any wifi or ethernet adapter.

Comment: the raspberry pi is attached through the ethernet adapter doesn't that mean it should respond? If not how should I proceed?

Comment: How do I determine the PC server's IP?

Comment: Start a CMD prompt from the Start menu and type in `ipconfig` and look for IP4 address for wired Ethernet adapter and use that.

Comment: running the app on 0.0.0.0 and sending the request to my wired lan ipv4 request gives ```Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0xb5af38f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 113] No route to host'))``` error, is there something I can do to fix this?

Comment: What happens if you start a Terminal on the RasPi and run `ping aa.bb.cc.dd` where `aa.bb.cc.dd` is the IP address of your Windows PC?

Comment: Destination host unreachable.

Comment: What is the IP address of your PC? Use `ipconfig` command. What is the IP address of your RasPi, use the `ifconfig` command - no, it is not `ipconfig`

Comment: PC is 169.254.204.220, pi is 192.168.86.79

Comment: Your PC doesn't appear to be connected to your network - it has a private IP address.

Comment: i provided the internal IP from the ethernet adapter. My raspberry pi is connected locally to the PC through an ethernet cable so I want them to communicate that way

Comment: Sorry, I can't provide all the basic network setup instructions for Windows and Linux on this site (StackOverflow). You'll need to get to the point where you can successfully ping the PC from the RasPi before it is going to work.

Comment: thats alright, thank you for your help anyways! Can you refer me to someplace I can look?

Answer (score 1):

Setting a static IP on the windows machine on the same network as the Pi and then sending the request to that IP (after enabling connections on port 6000) ended up solving my issue.